# How to delete a user's email from a MailChimp list using the API/Gibbon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, gibbon

I want to delete a user's email from my list in MailChimp using the API or Gibbon. However, there's no documentation about this in [Gibbon repo](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/master/README.markdown).

As of now, I can only delete the email from the MailChimp website.

Answer (score 2):

Would unsubscribe help you?

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).update(body: { status: "unsubscribed" })
```

Based on your comment and the mailchimp [docs](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#%20) try:

```
gibbon.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).delete
```

Comment: I want to delete it, not just unsubscribe them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this code; it works (Rails 5 / Gibbon 3.2.0):

```
Gibbon::Request.lists(list_id).members(lower_case_md5_hashed_email_address).delete
```